# Limitations on the number of items to use in apriori algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

Are there any limitations on the number of items to use in a transaction for applying apriori algorithm.

I have a dataset with just 20 records, but the number of items extend upto 900. I am getting memory issue when I apply the apriori algorithm on the dataset.

Thank you

Comment: There may be better implementations, and your support may be set too high. Also, there are plenty of alternative algorithms...

Comment: Can you be more explicit about what kind of language and framework you are using to get the memory issue?

Answer (score 1):

A first count on items can prune some of them. If you have only 20 records you can simply count the occurrence of items in dataset and prune those items which did not happen enough because their supersets also do not happen frequently and them make item-sets based on the rest of items.

Answer (score 1):

The question asks about the `Limitations on the number of items to use in apriori algorithm?` and I would answer in terms of space and time complexity.

Let us say that number of input transactions are N(=20) and the number of unique elements be R(approx 900). Assuming your threshold count is quite small (which means very few candidates are pruned), the time and space complexity for size i candidates would be `O(R^i)`. So you see, if very few candidates are pruned, the space (and time) requirements become exponential. It might seem unintutive at first, given that you have only 20 transactions. But the bottleneck is the number of candidates which increases exponentially with number of items.